# How to use PHP to generate PDF from HTML which gets duplicated on both halves of the PDF (landscape version)

Tags: php, html, tcpdf, fpdf, dompdf

I'm writing in PHP and using DOMPDF, FPDF, and TCPDF to render PDF documents.

Does anyone know exactly what the script would be to render an HTML formatted PDF to where the html is repeated on both halves of a landscape oriented PDF page? I'll include an image as to show exactly what I mean.

The trick is to have absolutely no margins, and it be Letter size, landscape formatted at the end.

[image: HTML Rendered two halves of page PDF]

Here's some code that might work, but I guess I'm asking for more of the HTML side of things.

```
use Dompdf\Dompdf;

// instantiate and use the dompdf class
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->loadHtml('myFile.html');

// (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
$dompdf->setPaper('Letter', 'landscape');

// Render the HTML as PDF
$dompdf->render();
```

Comment: StackOverflow is not a *give me the code* kind of girl. ;)

Comment: @JayBlanchard I realize this, but I finally got the issue handled. My answer is posted. By the way, I remember you from one of my previously asked questions. Thanks for being there for me, even now lol

Comment: @JayBlanchard I need help with a separate question. Hoping you can assist me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36752092/how-to-overlay-write-on-top-of-existing-pdf-with-html-generated-pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: You need this resource: https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf

my PHP DOMPDF code:

```
$fp = fopen('file_html.html','w');

require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");
spl_autoload_register('DOMPDF_autoload');

function pdf_create($html, $filename, $paper, $orientation, $stream=TRUE)
{
    ini_set("memory_limit", "50M");
    $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
    $dompdf->set_paper($paper,$orientation);
    $dompdf->load_html($html);
    $dompdf->render();
    $pdf = $dompdf->output();
    @file_put_contents($filename . ".pdf", $pdf);
}

$filename = 'myPDFFileName';
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$html = file_get_contents('file_html.html'); 
pdf_create($html,$filename,'Letter','landscape');
```

This pulls all the HTML from "file_html.html" and renders it as PDF named "myPDFFileName.pdf" into the same folder as the main PHP file.

Here's my html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        @page { margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px; }
        body {
            height:100%;
            margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
            background-size: 100% 100%;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }
        div.mainLayout{float:left;width:50%}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="mainLayout" style="height:100%">
        <p>Context</p>
    </div>
    <div class="mainLayout" style="height:100%">
        <p>Context</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Got exactly the result I was looking for.